# Centered button gets slightly shifted in Chrome

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, google-chrome

My html code looks like this (using Bootstrap):

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-1" style="width: 37.5%">
        <span class="dualselect">
            <select class="form-control input-default select-inline" style="width: 100%" multiple="multiple">
            </select>
        </span>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-1" align="center">
        <div class="dualselect">
            <div class="ds_arrow">
                <button class="btn btn-inverse">
                    <i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i>
                </button>
                <br/>
                <button class="btn btn-inverse">
                    <i class="fa fa-chevron-left"></i>
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4"  style="width: 37.5%">
        <span class="dualselect">
            <select class="form-control input-default select-inline" style="width: 100%" multiple="multiple">
            </select>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

This works perfectly fine in IE or Firefox. In Chrome the buttons with arrows are not perfectly aligned:
[image: the buttons]

The problem seems to be with `align="center"`. When removed, the buttons are aligned in all the browsers but I want them centered. How do I do that properly?

Comment: Probably won't fix the problem, but I believe it is recommended to use `style="text-align:center"` instead of `align="left"`.

Comment: It would be helpful in the future if you could post it in a fiddle using [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net), but it looks like [j08691](http://stackoverflow.com/users/616443/j08691) [figured it out for us](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24512213/centered-button-gets-slightly-shifted-in-chrome/24512294#24512294).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm a little surprised all browsers aren't showing the same result that Chrome does. The problem is the white space in your code. Remove it around the buttons code so it looks like this:

```
<button class="btn btn-inverse">
    <i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i>
</button><br/><button class="btn btn-inverse">
    <i class="fa fa-chevron-left"></i>
</button>
```

**[bootply example](http://www.bootply.com/fz89WOviXM)**

Answer (score 2):

An alternative would be to put each `<button>` in it's own separate `<div>`, and then eliminate the `<br/>`, thereby allowing you to keep whitespace for code aesthetics.

Answer (score 0):

You can also go other way:

Make your "row" class with attribute "position: relative", then in your "col-md-1" class set attribute "position:absolute, left: 50%, margin-left: -yourwidth in px" and you will get centered your "col-md-1".

But keep in mind that you will need also to edit your other "col-md-4"